# Vue.js cache method outcome?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I currently have a loop which calls the same function twice in that loop like so:

```
<div class="checkbox" v-for="(value, key) in range">
    <input type="checkbox" :disabled="count(Number(key)) === 0">

    <span class="items">{{ count(Number(key)) }}</span>
</div>
```

Because the `count` method is being called twice it makes it harder to debug the `count` function because on something like a `console.log` all values will appear twice.

The first count method simply checks if it is zero while the other represents the count. Is there a simple way to re-use the outcome of the `count` method so I don't actually have to call it twice. There is no need to call it again when I already have the outcome.

Something like a computed property won't work because I need to pass the current iteration key.

Comment: You can refactor it: instead of looping `range` you can create a computed property, say (pseudocode) `compCountRange = {rangeKey1: count(Number(rangeKey1)), ...similar pairs}` and loop though it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly by design a method will always re-render, there is no cache availible afaik:

> In comparison, a method invocation will always run the function
> whenever a re-render happens.
>
> Why do we need caching? Imagine we have
> an expensive computed property A, which requires looping through a
> huge Array and doing a lot of computations. Then we may have other
> computed properties that in turn depend on A. Without caching, we
> would be executing A’s getter many more times than necessary! In cases
> where you do not want caching, use a method instead.

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

By the way I think it's still possible to use a computed property most of the time:

```
computed: {
    rangeWithCount() {
        // assuming that range is an array, otherwise use Object.entries()
        return this.range.map((value, key) => {
            // assuming value is already an object, otherwise create a new one
            return Object.assign({}, value, {
                count: foo(key)
            });
        })
    }
}
```

And just iter over the computed prop:

```
<div class="checkbox" v-for="value in rangeWithCount">
    <input type="checkbox" :disabled="value.count === 0">

    <span class="items">{{ value.count }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a really creative way to make a computed prop, I will try to make my example work in a similar fashion. Thanks for answering.